# Algorithm to define pairs from a list

Tags: algorithm, scala, language-agnostic, hlist

Christmas is coming: it is time to determine who is going to make a gift to whom. I'm looking for such an algorithm.

Taking a list `(1 to 10)` for instance, create random pairs ensuring that:

- everybody item is associated to another item;
- none of the items is associated to itself;
- every item is associated once and only once.

So obviously, a simple shuffle is not enough:

```
Random.shuffle(1 to 10)
  .toSeq
  .zipWithIndex
```

Eg:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 1
4 -> 3
```

But not (`1` makes a gift to itself):

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
4 -> 2
```

I've been thinking to constraints on an HList but:

- I haven't been able to express it
- It might be a bit overkill (even if it is funny)
- There might be algorithms that ensure that "by construction"

Comment: You could simply repeat the shuffle until the conditions are met, will probably only take two or three attempts.

Comment: That's actually an option: it will probably work. But just for curiosity, I was wondering if there was something more elegant.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz doesn't need to repeat the entire shuffle. Where I work, we use a beanie: throw all the names in, everybody picks one; if you get to gift yourself, just put your name back and pick another.

Comment: There is one situation in which it does not work: when the last picks his own name. Another has to put back his paper.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/generating-a-random-derangement

Comment: Thanks Paul. That's overkill too... but very interesting!

Comment: On what range are you planning to run this algorithm to? It worth to have max/min boundaries.

Comment: In the "real" life, no more than 10 I guess. But the question is wider since this is only curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this simple algorithm should to the trick.

1. Shuffle the initial list
2. Associate index `i` to index `i+1` (modulo the size of the list)

This should be random enough for the need.

```
val people = Random.shuffle(Seq("a", "b", "c", "d"))

val associationIndices = (0 to people.length-1)
  .map(left => (left, (left + 1) % people.length))
  .foreach(assoc => println(s"${people(assoc._1)} -> ${people(assoc._2)}"))
```

Result is:

```
c -> d
d -> a
a -> b
b -> c
```

It works as long as the list has at least 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Foolproof solution: assign indexes to the names at random; pick a random prime number N (other than the number of person if this number is itself a prime) and apply a rotation on the list of indexes N positions (modulo the number of persons).

Java code (any java code is scala code, right?)

```
ArrayList<String> names=
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Ann","Bob","Ed","Kim","Sue","Tom"));
SecureRandom rng=new SecureRandom(); // better seed it
String rndNames[]=new String[names.size()];
for(int i=0; names.size()>0; i++) {
  int removeAt=rng.nextInt(names.size());
  rndNames[i]=names.remove(removeAt);
}
int offset=1; // replace this with a random choice of a 
              // number coprime with rndNames.length, followed by
              // offset = (randomPrime % rndNames.length)
              // 1 will do just fine for the offset, it is a valid value anyway
for(int i=0; i<rndNames.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(rndNames[i] +"->"+rndNames[(i+offset) % rndNames.length]);
}
```

Result:

```
Ann->Sue
Sue->Bob
Bob->Ed
Ed->Tom
Tom->Kim
Kim->Ann
```

Comment: Can you enumerate a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

just a mock up example: 
There are some scenarios to look at:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random

val n = 5
val rnd = new Random()
val result = ListBuffer.fill(n)( (0, 0) )
```

I am sure this could be optimised.

```
while( result.exists(x => x._1 == 0 && x._2 == 0) == true){
  val idx = result.zipWithIndex
  val p = idx.find(x => x._1._1 == 0 && x._1._2 == 0)
  p match {
    case None => Unit// ???
    case Some(x) => {
      val r = rnd.nextInt(n)
      if (result.exists(r => r._2 == r && x._2 != r) == false)
        result(x._2) = (x._2 + 1, r + 1)
    }
  }
}


result.foreach(x => println(x._1 + " : " + x._2 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Set` will insure no duplicates and, since a `Set` has no defined order, iterating over it will appear randomized.

```
val names = Set("Ann","Bob","Ed","Kim","Sue","Tom") // alphabetical
```

Then make your round-robin associations.

```
val nameDraw = (names.sliding(2) ++ Iterator(Set(names.last,names.head)))
                  .map(x => x.head -> x.last).toMap
//nameDraw = Map(Sue -> Ann, Ann -> Tom, Tom -> Bob, Bob -> Ed, Ed -> Kim, Kim -> Sue)
```